# iPhone - extending a class delegate

Tags: iphone, class

OK, I know how to create a class extension, using something like that:

on .h

```
@interface UIButton (myExtensionName) 

// my extended methods

@end
```

and then on .m

```
@implementation UIButton (myExtensionName)

// my implementations

@end
```

But how do I declare the extended delegates I may create?

If this was a normal class I would do

```
@protocol myExtensionName <NSObject>
// my delegate declarations
@end
```

but how do I do that on a class extension?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not want to take credit for an answers that already got posted here, so here's the link :

[Defining categories for protocols in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521267/defining-categories-for-protocols-in-objective-c)