# Passing Progress Bar Information to the View Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiprogressview

I have a class which handled the downloads and provides progress information.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [recievedData appendData:data];
    self.recievedlength = self.recievedlength + [data length];

    // Calculating progress
    self.progress = 0;
    self.progress = ((float)recievedlength / [filesize floatValue]);
    // NSLog(@"%f",self.progress);

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(passProgress) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I have the following selector which returns the progress information int form of float, in the same class :

- (float) passProgress
  {
      //NSLog(@"%f",self.progress);
      return self.progress;
  }

My Question is, how do I update the UIProgressView (progress bar) in the MainViewController. The following does not work.

```
NSLog(@"Progress %f",[classInstance passProgress]);
```

Any ideas thanks. I do not want to write the download code in the MainViewController.

Comment: Maybe I'm forgetting something here, but why not just call the method on the UIProgressView to update the value directly from `connection:didReceiveData:`?

Comment: How do I do that. The code for the view is contained in MainViewController.m . How do I connect it in the interface ??

Comment: You just need to create, in your class to handle downloads, a reference to either MainViewController or the UIProgressView and connect it at runtime.  For example, maybe when you initialize the download class you pass it a reference to the UIProgressView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a `protocol` in your download manager. Adopt that protocol in your main view controller.

Comment: Can you point me to any examples. I have never written a protocol.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521267/defining-categories-for-protocols-in-objective-c