# How do I define a category that adds methods to classes which implement a particular protocol?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I want to add some methods to subclasses of NSManagedObject that implement the SOManagedObject protocol.  I've tried defining it like this:

```
@interface NSManagedObject <SOManagedObject> (MyExtensionMethods)
    ...
@end
```

...but that doesn't seem to be valid.  How do I define a category that adds methods to classes which implement a particular protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining such a category on all such classes in general is not easily solvable. But your actual problem seems simpler: How does one add a category method to `NSManagedObject` for use only with subclasses that implement `<SOManagedObject>`? This is solvable.

What you want to do is add the method to `NSManagedObject`, then check that the instance you're working with can handle the messages you want to send it from `<SOManagedObject>`.

Let us suppose that we are given:

```
/* SOManagedObject.h */
@protocol SOManagedObject
- (void)frobble_so;
- (void)bobble_so;
@end
```

Now let's add a category method to all `NSManagedObject` subclasses that implement `SOManagedObject`:

```
/* NSManagedObject+SOConvenience.h */
@interface NSManagedObject (SOConvience)
/* Frobbles and bobbles - no effect on non-<SOManagedObject>-conforming
 * instances. */
- (void)frobbleAndBobble_so;
@end
```

To do so, we implement the method like so:

```
/* NSManagedObject+SOConvenience.m */
@implementation NSManagedObject (SOConvenience)
- (void)frobbleAndBobble_so
{
    if (![self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SOManagedObject)]) return;

    NSLog(@"%s: Thunderbirds are GO! Let's frobble and bobble!", __func__);
    [self frobble_so];
    [self bobble_so];
}
@end
```

You could optionally assert to ensure you are not sending the method to the wrong objects, or you could use `respondsToSelector:` instead of checking for protocol conformance. Whatever floats your boat, but this general tack should take you where you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. A similar question to this was answered earlier:

[Defining categories for protocols in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521267/defining-categories-for-protocols-in-objective-c/1521431#1521431)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the question; I don't think it's possible to do what you're trying to do without messing with the Objective-C runtime. See Dave's comment below for why my answer is incorrect.

---

You should be able to do this if you swap the protocol and category notation like so:

```
@interface NSManagedObject (MyExtensionMethods) <SOManagedObject>
    ...
@end
```

Comment: Nope, this is a category on `NSManagedObject`.  It's declaring that `NSManagedObject` now conforms to the protocol `<SOManagedObject>`, not that the category applies to `NSManagedObject<SOManagedObject>`'s.

Comment: Wow, I definitely didn't read the question carefully enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adam Sharp [posted a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17740636/35690) that worked for me.

It involves 3 steps:

1. Defining the methods you want to add as `@optional` on a protocol.
2. Making the objects you want to extend conform to that protocol.
3. Copying those methods into those objects at runtime.

Check out the link for the full details.